# Is calculating BigInt.pow(&BigInt) possible?

Tags: math, rust, biginteger

I want to calculate:

```rust
let n1 = BigInt(256);
let n2 = BigInt(1024);
let n3 = BigInt(3);
let n4 = BigInt(40);

let res = n1.pow(n2.pow(n3) * n4);
let len = res.to_string().len();
```

I tried `num` crate, but its `pow()` method only supports u32 as exponent. Is there any crate that supports BigInt as exponent? Or is it just too big to be calculated?

Comment: Not quite too big for all cases but getting there. 2^32 bits is half a gigabyte.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says `256 ^ (1024 ^ 3 * 40)` is `2.217 x 10^103433118919`. It would take about 40GB to store that number if my math was right.

Comment: You're trying to calculate 2^343597383680 as a string which has over 103 billion digits. How much RAM do you have? If you have hundreds of GB you might be able to do it by accumulating a bunch of smaller factors. Find q,d,r around the square root of exponent e such that e = qd+r then calculate x^e = ((x^q)^d)*(x^r)

Comment: Condensing the comments: there is no circumstance in which you want to actually _evaluate_ "something to the power superhuge" because not only do you not have the system memory to do so, you also can't _do_ anything with a single number result that takes a lifetime to read through. Let alone getting the CPU to then do anything further with that number. You'd be waiting years. So use a symbolic maths library to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer for the `BigInt.pow(&BigInt)`, but only an answer to this specific problem. This question in this post is "How many digits does this number have?" and it can be converted to a math problem.

First simplify this expression.

```
BigInt(256).pow(BigInt(1024).pow(BigInt(3)) * BigInt(40))
=> 256 ^ (1024 ^ 3 * 40)
=> 2 ^ (2^36 * 5)
```

And "how many digits" can be calculated by "log(10, X)" for decimal number.

```
log(10, 2 ^ (2^36 * 5))
= 2 ^ 36 * 5 * log(10, 2)
```

Which can be calculated easily. And the result is approximately `103433118919.34569`.